# How can I call TRttiProperty.SetValue for non-string properties when I have the value as a string?

Tags: delphi, rtti

I want to serialize an Object in Delphi and I'm using the new RTTI. Butwhen I load the values from the storage, they are retreived as string,s and TRttiProperty.SetValue needs a TValue as a second argument. Thus an exception is raised when I set the value of a property declared as a double to '5.1' or '5'

I also Tried using `TValue.From()` method with no success.

here is a piece of code which explains where things go wrong.

```
var P: TRttiProperty;

.... 

// P now is the property which is declared as a double or integer
P.SetValue(Self, '3'); //<-- this raises an exception.
```

EDIT: Question is how to get it to set the value of a property which isn't string type, using a string data type, but which contains valid data. (such as the above case)

Comment: @Rob: Looks like he's reading numbers serialized to text and trying to deserialize them, and he's confused by the lack of implicit conversions from string->numeric types.

Comment: Edited the question to add a clarification as to what I'm asking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeah, you're trying to assign '3' (a string) to a numeric property.  The RTTI system doesn't do 
implicit type conversions.  Try something like this:

```
procedure DeserializeProperty(P: TRttiProperty; s: string);
var
  v: TValue;      
begin
  case p.PropertyType.TypeKind of
    tkInteger: v := StrToInt(s);
    tkFloat: v := StrToFloat(s);
    tkString: v := s;
  end;
  p.SetValue(self, v);
end;
```

This is obviously not a finished product, but it should be enough to get you started.